# How Can I separate MainActivity.java into 2 or more classes?

Tags: android

I want to split MainActivity.java into 2 classes where in MainActivity's onItemSelected() method will call another class's setInputOutputSpinners() method 
Below is my full code for `MainActivity.java` :

```
package com.gazzali.spinitmeow;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinnerMainChoice;
    Spinner spinnerInputChoice;
    Spinner spinnerOutputChoice;

    EditText getInputValueID;
    double inputValue;

    TextView outputValue;

    Button buttonConvert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* ------------ Main code Starts Here ----------------*/

        /* Main conversion Type choice with Spinner (Drop Down menu)*/
        spinnerMainChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDMainChoice);
        // [IMPORTANT] Set Spinner Click Listener
        spinnerMainChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterMainChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.MainChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapterMainChoice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinnerMainChoice.setAdapter(adapterMainChoice);

        /* Input Conversion type choice with Spinner */
        spinnerInputChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDInputChoice);
        spinnerInputChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        /* Output Conversion type choice with Spinner */

        spinnerOutputChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDOutputChoice);
        spinnerOutputChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        /* for input and output fields */
        getInputValueID = findViewById(R.id.editTextIDInputValue);
        String inputValueString = getInputValueID.getText().toString();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputValueString))
        {
            try
            {
                inputValue = Double.parseDouble(inputValueString);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        outputValue = findViewById(R.id.textViewIDOutputValue);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. retrieve the selected item
        String selectedMainChoice = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Log.i("Selected", selectedMainChoice);
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected: " + selectedMainChoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /* Here I want to make the separation, But my methods are not working. */
        SpinnerSelects spinnerSelects = new spinnerSelects(spinnerInputChoice, spinnerOutputChoice);
        spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(selectedMainChoice);

    }

    protected void setInputOutputSpinners(String selectedMainChoice) {
        switch (selectedMainChoice)
        {
            case "Length": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));
            }
            break;

            case "Temperature": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TemperatureChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TemperatureChoices_array)));
            }
            break;

            case "Weight": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WeightChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WeightChoices_array)));
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }

}
```

I tried to make another class, but sometimes the Spinner can't be resolved, then I create constructors in Android, it solved, but now another type problem coming in. Like: in the new class I tried to make something like below, but now `getResources()` can't be resolved.

```
package com.gazzali.spinitmeow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class spinnerSelects {
    Spinner spinnerInputChoice, spinnerOutputChoice;
    public spinnerSelects(Spinner spinnerInputChoiceFromMain, Spinner spinnerOutputChoiceFromMain) {
        this.spinnerInputChoice = spinnerInputChoiceFromMain;
        this.spinnerOutputChoice = spinnerOutputChoiceFromMain;
    }

    protected void setInputOutputSpinners(String selectedMainChoice) {
        switch (selectedMainChoice)
        {
            case "Length": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));
            }
            break;

            case "Temperature": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TemperatureChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TemperatureChoices_array)));
            }
            break;

            case "Weight": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WeightChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WeightChoices_array)));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me. I'm tottaly newbie in android development.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `setInputOutputSpinners` in your `MainActivity`, and make the `setInputOutputSpinners` method a `public` method in your `spinnerSelects` class.

---

**Update** - Sample code for the comment question

```
// This can then be called in the MainActivity using,
// spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(this, selectedMainChoice);

protected void setInputOutputSpinners(Context context, String selectedMainChoice) {
        switch (selectedMainChoice)
        {
            case "Length": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));

            //Similarly so in the rest of the places
    }
```

Comment: What error does it show? Add your 'updated' code to the question.

Comment: It shows `Cannot resolve method getResources() ` in the second class

Comment: Pass the `context` to the method `setInputOutputSpinners` and use `context.getResources()` instead.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a sample, mark my answer as correct if it works (or comment if there are any more issues). Cheers.

Comment: Now it's showing that It can't extract StringArray using `context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)))`;

Comment: Try `spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(getApplicationContext(), selectedMainChoice);` instead of `spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(this, selectedMainChoice);`.

Comment: @Jim , I've updated my own answer. Your method was not completely right, but it greatly to find what can be done to fix my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Finally, I think I solved my problem. Thanks to  **Chrisvin Jim** for your hint, Your answer gave the hint what I needed to do. I needed to modify these pieces of codes.

inside `MainActivity.java` :

```
/* Implement object of spinnerSelects class*/
            spinnerSelects spinnerSelects = new spinnerSelects(spinnerInputChoice, spinnerOutputChoice);
            /* the main EVIL '(context) this' in  the 2nd parameter, 5 hours wasted, but I learnt many more */
            spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(selectedMainChoice, this);
```

And inside `spinnerSelects.java` file :

```
public void setInputOutputSpinners(String selectedMainChoice, Context context) {
    switch (selectedMainChoice)
    {
        case "Length": {
            adapterInputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                    R.array.LengthChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapterOutputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                    R.array.LengthChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            setInputOutputDropDownAndAdapter();
        }
        break;

        case "Temperature": {
            adapterInputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                    R.array.TemperatureChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            adapterOutputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                    R.array.TemperatureChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            setInputOutputDropDownAndAdapter();
        }
        break;

        case "Weight": {
            adapterInputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                    R.array.WeightChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            adapterOutputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                    R.array.WeightChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            setInputOutputDropDownAndAdapter();

        }
        break;
    }

}
private void setInputOutputDropDownAndAdapter() {
    adapterInputChoice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(adapterInputChoice);
    adapterOutputChoice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(adapterOutputChoice);
}
```